# J query call VB Behind Code function to return json?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, vb.net, get

I am trying to call a behind code function to return a json to jquery?

```
Public Function GetBushCampBooking() As string
  Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
  conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn").ConnectionString

  Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
  Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
  Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("BushCampBookingsGet", conn)
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  Try
     conn.Open()
     Dim Adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
     Adp.Fill(ds)

  Catch ex As Exception

  Finally
     conn.Close()
  End Try

  dt = ds.Tables(0)
  Dim json As String

  json = GetJson(dt)

  Return json
End Function
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "BushCamp.aspx/GetBushCampBooking",
     data: "{}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(result) {
         alert(result.d);
         //$("#content").html(result.d);
     }
});
```

---

My Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

 http://localhost:10131/Hlh_shares/Content/BushCamp/BushCamp.aspx/GetBushCampBooking?{}
```

Comment: Internal server error means there's a problem with the VB script.  Can you run it directly on the server (or step through it) so you can see the error details?

Comment: You can not call Direct Page Function you have to Create Web Service or You have to called page using qurey string and reponse As Json format string

Answer (score 0):

Add to vb page:

> Imports System.Web.Services

Then make function shared `Public Shared Function GetBushCampBooking() As string`

Then make it a webmethod:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetBushCampBooking() As string
```